# Block .exe files

Tags: c++, winapi, file-monitoring, api-hook

For a small project that I'm working on, I need to prevent ".exe" files from running and know the path of the file that was trying to run. Maybe windows API hooking can help me, but I am unsure, and I haven't worked with it.

Can anyone guide me about how I can do it, possibly with API hooking?

Comment: you can't prevent any .exe files because Windows processes also need to run and they're .exe files

Comment: Sorry I was not accurate. I meant '.exe' files that do not belong to Windows.

Comment: Smell like a XY problem. Why do you want to block some other EXE in your own little EXE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hooking in usermode is going to be unreliable, to really do this you should write a driver and use [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutine).

If you only want "safe" applications, use Windows S-mode.

If you want to do this without writing code, use [AppLocker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview).

Comment: Thank you. Should I do the same thing if I want to do a simpler thing for the first step and get the file's path that started to run?

Comment: You can use WMI to get notifications about new processes but the process has already started by that point.

Comment: The [process creation callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nc-ntddk-pcreate_process_notify_routine) doesn't appear to have any return values. How would one revert process creation from here? Maybe a [file system filter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/about-file-system-filter-drivers) is a better fit for the problem.

Comment: @IInspectable The Ex version allows you to set a NTSTATUS in the 3rd parameter if you don't want to kill the process from usermode. It really depends on where you want to implement the filtering.